# Can a Bitcoin (secp256k1) key be converted to a Ed25519 (Tor v3) key?

Tags: tor, secp256k1

If I have `secp256k1` keypair that is widely known, like a Bitcoin address, can I convert that into a `Ed25519` key pair such that someone could access a .onion address in a deterministic way?

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin key could sign a message containing the onion address. There are several other alternatives but there isn't any way to do this without the key holder producing a message of some kind.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now that I think about it because there is no way to get the ECC coordinates from the hashed address alone.

Comment: Even if you had the full public key, you can't convert it to a ed25519 public key in such a way that the private key can be converted in a compatible manner. The secp256k1 and ed25519 have different structure.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't convert them since they are defined over different curves.